# Creating a link between two vectors in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, vector

This is a conceptual question, so I am not providing the "working code" for this reason.

Imagine one has two std::vector of different types and different number of entities, just for example:

```
vector <int> A;
vector <string> B;
```

One has a set of rules following which one can associate any members of A with some(or none) of the members of B.

Is there a way to "store" this connection?

I was thinking that one of the ways to do so is having a `vector <map <int, vector <string> > >` or `vector <map <int, vector <string*> > >`, but this solutions seems to me unreliable (if A contains two same numbers for example) and I assume there are much more elegant solutions somewhere there.

Comment: As you describe it a `std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>>` seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , that is a matter of what would actually need - to quickly retrieve a->b or b->a. And therefore maybe more complex solution will be in handy.
Also, nothing stops us from having the same objects also in B :)

Comment: Provide more info - if there are duplicates in A (B), how would they map to B (A)? Or do actually mean your associating the vector positions/indices? This is a question more about functions (math ones) then code.

Comment: @kabanus for example each letter can be presented as a number. and then you link the numbers in A to strings in B by weather they contain(or not) the specific letter(case insensitive). the vise-versa operation(B->A) would then also make sence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement some *database* techniques:  indices.  Place your data into a single `vector` then create `std::map` for each way you want to index your data or relate the data.

Rather than 2 vectors, make one vector of structures:

```
struct Datum
{
  int value;
  string text;
};

// The database
std::vector<Datum> database;

// An index table by integer
std::map<int, // Key
         unsigned int vector_index> index_by_value;

// An index table, by text
std::map<std::string, // Key
         unsigned int index_into_vector> index_by text;
```

The index tables give you a quick method to find things in the database, without having to sort the database.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::multiset` of `std::pair`s would be able to map multiple `int*`s to zero or more `std::string*`s:

```
std::multiset < std::pair<int*, std::vector<std::string*>>> map_A_to_B;
```

Example:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A{3,3,1,5};
    std::vector<std::string> B{"three a", "three b", "one", "five", "unknown"};
    std::multiset < std::pair<int*, std::vector<std::string*>>> map_A_to_B{
        {&A[0],{&B[0],&B[1]}},
        {&A[1],{&B[0],&B[1],&B[4]}},
        {&A[2],{&B[2]}},
        {&A[3],{&B[3]}},
    };

    for(auto e : map_A_to_B) {
        for(auto s : e.second) {
            std::cout << *e.first << " linked to " << *s << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << "------------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

produces:

```
3 linked to three a
3 linked to three b
------------------------------
3 linked to three a
3 linked to three b
3 linked to unknown
------------------------------
1 linked to one
------------------------------
5 linked to five
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it seems like you want an actual mapping (as in math, from a set A to a set B) that is general (not one-to-one or onto). First you have to conceptually understand what you want. First, you want a mapping between a class A (say int in your example) to B (string). Let's template this:

```
template <class From, class To>
bool isMapped(From A,To B) {
    return (//Code representing mapping,say check if A=int->char is in B=string)
}
```

Now the mapping of a `From` value to a `To` vector is (in math terms) the range in "To" which is reachable (`isMapped`) form this value:

```
template<class From, class To>
List<To>& getRange(From value, To range) {
    List<To> result();
    for (const auto& toValue : range) {
         if(isMapped(value,toValue) 
             result.push_back(toValue);
    return result;
```

This will return the range the `From` value is mapped to in the `To` vector, with duplicates if they appear more than once in the range. Another option (maybe better) would be to iterate over indices instead of values in the range, and return a Boolean vector of the length of `range` with `true` in the indices where From is mapped to.

Similarly you would need to define the opposite mapping. Probably you couldn't make this completely general, and maybe even templates won't fit this simply - you would need to give more specifics.

So concluding, the mapping from A to B would be a vector of length of vector A (the domain) of vectors of length B (domain) with True/False in the relevant indices.

There are of course, more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Boost to implement a [bidirectional map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html) - that would allow you to use either of the values as a key. [Here is an example of how to use it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/example/bimap.cpp). But, in short: (usage only, without definitions)

```
struct from {}; // tag for boost

typedef bidirectional_map<int, std::string>::type bi_map;

bi_map values;
values.insert(bi_map::value_type(123, "{"));

// ...
// ...

bi_map::iterator it = values.get<from>().find(123);
if (it != values.end()) {
    cout << "Char #123 is " << it->second << endl;
    // and in the opposite case, where "it" is the result of:
    // values.get<to>().find("{")
    // it->second would be 123, so you have access to both items
}
```